# How to reload wildfly using CLI

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-cli

How is it done?  I have scoured the net and no combination that I have found and tried works.

According to this https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.2/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/reload_the_application_server_using_the_management_cli

it's easy: just run

```
:reload
```

But that does not work for me - I get

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0031: No operation named 'reload' exists at address []",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

This is what I've tried:

[image]

Either the CLI command (i.e. when inside the CLI) or the command line (i.e. as passed to /jboss-cli.sh) would be very much appreciated.

By the way, I think I am running in standalone mode (certainly, there is only one instance running on my computer).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not running in standalone mode which is why the `:reload` operation and `reload` command do not exist. In your screenshot it shows `[domain@localhost:9990]`. That means you're running in domain mode.

For domain mode you can still reload however. You just need to execute the operation on the host you're working on. By default the host name is `master`. The command would be:

```
/host=master:reload
```

Comment: Ah ok thanks.  How do I establish what my host is?  I tried both `/host=master:reload` and `/host=localhost:reload` and neither works.  I thought it might be localhost as I do `connect localhost` to get into the CLI, but no dice.

Comment: :reload != reload and the host name is the one defined on the host.xml that you are using

Comment: You'd need to know what your host name is. Note this is the domain host not the hostname of the computer. What does `:read-children-names(child-type=host)` return? Also note you can use tab completion, `/host=<TAB>` to see a list of the hosts.